# how to add a photo from android to a newly created google's calendar event?

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

I want to build an android app that browses a photo and create a google calendar event

witht the photo as an attachment.

What API should I use? is it possible?

I have googles around and didn't find a way to do so.

Maybe because files attachment is relatively new to google's calendar?